# Excel variant array contents to file, with row contents joined

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

please bear with me as I'm very new to VBA, with prior experience primarily from Rhinoscript and other dedicated scripting options. The question is really very simple and I reckon someone can answer this very quickly, as I'm poor with arrays in VBA:

I have a spreadsheet where the objective is to import a number of values and text strings (resulting in some blanks) into e.g. A:L. This is done manually. I need to read these values into an array and then print them into a file so that each file row corresponds to a row of columns in the array. Currently I cannot seem to be able to convert the variant array into a string array (apparently necessary) and then join the subarrays into temporary arrays which are printed into the file. The following bit I've managed to scrape together results in a file output where each array value is on a single row, where as I'd like the contents of e.g. A1:L1 to be printed on single row.

```
Sub writerangetofile()

'Write data to a text file

'Declaring variables
Dim valarray() As Variant
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long

'Set array as range
Sheet1.Activate
valarray() = Range("A1:L40")

'Setting the name and the path of text file based on workbook path
sFName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Output.txt"

'Get an unused file number
intFNumber = FreeFile

'Create a new file (or overwrite an existing one)
Open sFName For Output As #intFNumber

For R = 1 To UBound(valarray, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
   For C = 1 To UBound(valarray, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
        Print #intFNumber, valarray(R, C)
   Next C
Next R

'Close the text file
Close #intFNumber

End Sub
```

For simplicity as I've also not figured out how to obtain the last row with any content in it I've restricted the range to row 40 for now.

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I want elegantly? I've solved it by assigning single cells to variables, but I'd prefer to do it with an array. Ultimately I will later be interjecting a fixed text string after a recurring text string in the imported text, which is then followed by a numerical value obtained from a calculation.

Many thanks for any help and apologies for the ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have any issues, this versions shows how to determine the last row and column

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RangeToFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim arr As Variant, fName As String, fNumber As Long, txtLine As String

    fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Output.txt"   'File name & path based on workbook path

    Set ws = Sheet1 'set a reference to main sheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row         'find last row in column A
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column in row 1

    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "A"), ws.Cells(lr, lc))      'Copy range to array

    fNumber = FreeFile                  'get next available file number assigned by windows
    Open fName For Output As #fNumber   'create a new file, or overwrite an existing one

    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)                    '1st array dimension is rows
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)                '2nd array dimension is columns
            txtLine = txtLine & arr(r, c) & ", "   'concatenate each cell in row, on a line
        Next c                                     'the end of the row, moving to next one
        txtLine = Left(txtLine, Len(txtLine) - 2)  'remove the extra comma at end of line
        txtLine = txtLine & vbCrLf                 'append a carriage return to the line
    Next r
    txtLine = Left(txtLine, Len(txtLine) - 2)      'remove carriage return at end of line

    Print #fNumber, txtLine 'print entire text to the file with an extra carriage return
    Close #fNumber          'close the text file
End Sub
```

---

and this one transposes columns to rows:

```
Public Sub RangeToFileColumnsToRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim arr As Variant, fName As String, fNumber As Long, txtLine As String

    fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Output.txt"   'File name & path based on workbook path

    Set ws = Sheet1 'set a reference to main sheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row         'find last row in column A
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column in row 1

    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "A"), ws.Cells(lr, lc))      'Copy range to array

    fNumber = FreeFile                  'get next available file number assigned by windows
    Open fName For Output As #fNumber   'create a new file, or overwrite an existing one

    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)                    '2nd array dimension is columns
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)                '1st array dimension is rows
            txtLine = txtLine & arr(r, c) & ", "   'concatenate each cell in col, on a line
        Next r                                     'the end of the col, moving to next one
        txtLine = Left(txtLine, Len(txtLine) - 2)  'remove the extra comma at end of line
        txtLine = txtLine & vbCrLf                 'append a carriage return to the line
    Next c
    txtLine = Left(txtLine, Len(txtLine) - 2)      'remove carriage return at end of line

    Print #fNumber, txtLine 'print entire text to the file
    Close #fNumber          'close the text file
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I got a step forward:

```
For R = 1 To UBound(valarray, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.

    For C = 1 To UBound(valarray, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.

        ReDim Preserve tvalarray(1 To C) 'Reset the array dimension on each iteration of loop whilst keeping results
        'Input each single value into subarray for joining
        tvalarray(C) = valarray(R, C)
        'Join the subarray
        jstring = Join(tvalarray)

    Next C

    ReDim Preserve jvalarray(1 To R) 'Reset the array dimension on each iteration of loop whilst keeping results
    'Input the joined result into the new array
    jvalarray(R) = jstring
    'Print to file
    Print #intFNumber, jvalarray(R)

Next R
```

This seems to do the job, I'll see if I run into pitfalls later.